# Cannot initialize jScrollPane

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) plugin, what I did is to create the html structure:

```
<div id="resources_list"></div>
```

I imported the necessary file to include it:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="jquery.jscrollpane.css"/>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
```

and then in js I init the JscrollPane:

```
$('#resources_list').jScrollPane({ mouseWheelSpeed: 70 });
$('#resources_list').append('<div>Hello</div>')
$('#resources_list').append('<div>World</div>')
```

but I get this result:

[image]

in the console there aren't error, and the structure appears like this:

[image]

should be displayed with vertical scroll bar and as in the site example, what am I doing wrong?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NgNvf/89/)

Comment: Can you provide your html and a demo of the issue?

Comment: Please share your Jsfield link

Comment: @IrvinDominin check the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/NgNvf/89/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay problem fixed, I don't know why but for get it work you must surrond the initialization in a function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(function()
    {
        $('.results').jScrollPane({mouseWheelSpeed: 70});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you browser's developers console for errors. I suspect you have wrong path to jquery.jscrollpane.css. Becouse jScrollPane works, it make new html tags inside of the block, but this new tag is not styled.

Comment: Or try to use another custom scroll.
This is good: http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html